# How to implement Places AutoCompleteFragment in 2019 SINCE DEPRECATION

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

Trying to get autocomplete fragment to work in my code. TAG causes an error in the code, if you remove the Log statement it causes an error for the whole paragraph. it also does not let me TAG create a variable for tag to remove the error, if i do this the whole paragraph gets an error as well.

Have gone through the deprecation steps and added the new dependencies and imports and it still wont work...

also Places API is definitely already enabled

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile the `Places SDK for Android` provides this API:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0"
}
```

The [AutocompleteSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/widget/AutocompleteSupportFragment) in this package is not deprecated, but the whole package you are using. See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration), in case you may already have some code which runs against that deprecated package.

---

And if `TAG` is unknown, you probably should define it; for example:

```
private static final String TAG = "PlacesActivity";
```

Comment: I have tried to define the tag, but when i do it causes an error in the whole paragraph of code as mentioned.

Comment: I have seen and implemented all the code in the migration guide and it still does not work, along with the errors when i define the TAG :(